# R show variable list/header of Stata or SAS file in R without loading the complete dataset

Tags: r, import, sas, stata, preview

I am given very big (around 10 Gb each) datasets in both SAS and Stata format. I am going to read them into R for analysis.

Is there a way to show what variables (columns) they contain inside without reading the whole data file? I often only need some of the variables. I can view them of course from File Explorer, but it's not reproducible and takes a lot of time.

Both SAS and Stata are available on the system, but just opening a file might take a minute or so.

Comment: Do you have any access to Stata or SAS?

Comment: Yes, both are available, but just opening the files can take a minute or so.

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible - in the interim I'm building lookup tables for each file.

Comment: You can read in the first row (along with column headers) with `read_dta` and `read_sas` while specifying `n_max = 1` as an option. Both are included in the `haven` package.

Comment: If you want a vector of column headers, you could wrap your read call in `names()`

Comment: @JR96 that exactely what I now came up with too. `read_dta` is ideal as I imports the column labels from Stata and also has a `col_select` function now. If you post it as an answer underneat I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @JoanneDemmler Answer added below; I appreciate the consideration for XP. Glad this worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below for the `dta` solution, which you can update to `SAS` using `read_sas`.

```
library(haven)

# read in first row of dta 
dta_head <- read_dta("my_data.dta",
                     n_max = 1)

# get variable names of dta
dta_names <- names(dta_head)
```

After examining the names and labels of your `dta` file, you can then remove the `n_max = 1` option and read in full while possibly adding the `col_select` option specifying the subset of variables you wish to read in.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SAS run a proc contents or proc datasets to see the details of the dataset without opening it. You may want to do that anyways, so that you can verify variable types, lengths and formats.

```
libname myFiles 'path to your sas7bdatfiles';

proc contents data=myfiles.datasetName;
run;
```

Comment: That is sort of a solution, I guess it could be run from within R through a bash file. Not quite what I was looking for though. Thanks.

Comment: You said you had SAS on the system, the best way to verify types, formats and such is to see it in the original system.